# Selecting data from 3 tables to calculate inventory levels

Tags: sql, inventory-management

I am currently setting up an inventory system in phpgrid. I have 3 tables - products, orders, purchases. I am trying to list all of the PartNumber field from products and the total of the NumberReceived for each PartNumber from purchases along with the total of the NumberShipped for each PartNumber from orders.

From there I believe I can use phpgrid to display a virtual/calculated column that will subtract the NumberShipped from the NumberReceived and give me the current stock level of each PartNumber.

Looking for results something like this:

```
PartNumber   | Received  | Shipped  | (calculated) Qty On Hand
______________________________________________________________
12345        | 20        |  10      |  10
67890        | 40        |  5       |  35
```

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to join everything together to retrieve the data that I want. This SELECT displays some data but not every PartNumber with the proper calculations.

```
 "SELECT 
        p.id, 
        sum(p.NumberReceived) AS 'Received', 
        sum(o.NumberShipped) As 'Shipped' 
        FROM purchases p
        INNER JOIN orders o on p.id = o.ProductId
        GROUP BY p.id ", 
    "id", "purchases");
```

I realized that I need to have the PartNumber column in there in order to list all the data of the PartNumber field. So then I tried this - I think I'm close but this keeps giving me an error - PHPGRID_ERROR: Could not execute query. Error 102

```
"SELECT 
    prod.id,prod.PartNumber, 
    sum(pur.NumberReceived) AS 'Received', 
    sum(o.NumberShipped) As 'Shipped', 
    FROM products prod
    LEFT JOIN orders o ON prod.PartNumber = o.ProductId
    LEFT JOIN purchases pur ON prod.PartNumber = pur.ProductId", 
"id", "products");
```

I'm hoping someone could help steer me in the right direction. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

If you are summing you need to group by.  The following should work.  If not, send specific error message.
(you also had an extra comma after the last item in the select block)

```
SELECT 
    prod.id,prod.PartNumber, 
    sum(pur.NumberReceived) AS Received, 
    sum(o.NumberShipped) As Shipped 
    FROM products prod
    LEFT JOIN orders o ON prod.PartNumber = o.ProductId
    LEFT JOIN purchases pur ON prod.PartNumber = pur.ProductId"
    GROUP BY prod.id, prod.PartNumber;
```

Comment: Thank you. This did get me a step closer. The problem is now the sum of NumberReceived and NumberShipped look to be the total of all everything. How do I get the sum of NumberReceived for each PartNumber? And the sum of NumberShipped for each PartNumber?

Comment: That is exactly what this query will do -- sum the NumberReceived and NumberShipped by PartNumber.  Try it out.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not. I thought that's what this would do as well. Here's a screen shot of what I get when I run it. I know there is at least data for each PartNumber for the Received column in the database. https://photos.app.goo.gl/UmFtnEcTqdKz2N6X9

I appreciate your time. This has been driving me insane and it's nice to have a new set of eyes on it.

Comment: Check the links in the left join.  Does the PartNumber match the ProductID?  Or should it be prod.ID=o.ProductID?

Comment: Ah yes you are correct. So I got half of this to work - LEFT JOIN purchases pur ON prod.id = pur.ProductId is the first Join in the statement and that's returning the data I was expecting. The second line of the statement I have as LEFT JOIN orders o ON prod.id = o.ProductId and that's not returning the correct data. Any thoughts as to why the second part is returning some odd looking figures?  I've tried a few different combinations and I can't seem to get this to work.